# Font embedding in CSS

Tags: css, font-face

I'm about to use some custom fonts for my website.
I know that currently there are few websites providing free webfonts like: [Google WebFonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace%3aselect)

But, the font I want isn't there. I want to know if there is any way to convert this font that I have to a webfont. (my font extension is `TTF`)

Also, I downloaded a few webfonts, their extension was also `TTF`. Are webfonts something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different browsers handle webfonts differently. TTF will work in most browsers but not IE or on iPhones. I'd recommend checking out [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) as it has a lot of fonts on there including a @font-face generator that will help you set things up.

Comment: So converting the font using that website makes it available for all browsers?

Comment: Thanks. After long time looking for an answer, Font Squirrel solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Web fonts are nothing special; they can be TrueType fonts, as long as the browser supports that format (most do). To use a TrueType font in your CSS, use

```
@font-face {
    font-family: {given name};
    src: url({path to font file}) format('truetype');
}
```

Then use

```
font-family: {given name};
```

in any rules you want to use the font for.

Answer (score 1):

I've previously used [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to generate the web font files from a ttf.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) as a fallback for browsers that don't support css `@font-face`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the ttf files in combination with @font-face. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webfonts/quick/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.truefontfamily.com/) might be of use -

make sure the license for the font you are using allows it though.